# XNA Calculate two points of triangle with given Z

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, intersection

I want to calculate the two points of a 3D triangle that have a specified Z coordinate. I guess the way to do this would be to somehow create a plane which is perfectly flat with my given Z coordinate and then calculate where the triangle intersects with it (or is this wrong).

If you know how to do this in any way please help. I have searched for but have not really found anything that seems to work.

Comment: I don't think you have enough information to find the 3rd point. I believe you'll also need (at least one of) the angles of the corners adjacent to the missing point.

Comment: I think I have enough info, I have the 3 Vector3 points of a triangle and I just want to calculate a linesegment of where this triangle intersects with a "plane" (As in a flat surface with a given Z coordinate). This surface could also possibly be defined as a rectangle...

Comment: I see, I read the question as you had two points and were trying to find the third based off a plane. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that I hope is intuitive enough, assuming `z0` is the Z value of your intersection plane:

- start with an empty list of points `L`
- if `(A.z - z0) * (B.z - z0) <= 0`, it means AB intersects the plane:

  - compute `u = (B.z - z0) / (B.z - A.z)`
  - add point `B + u * (A - B)` to list `L`
- if `(A.z - z0) * (C.z - z0) <= 0`:

  - compute `u = (C.z - z0) / (C.z - A.z)`, add point `C + u * (A - C)` to list `L`
- if `(B.z - z0) * (C.z - z0) <= 0`:

  - compute `u = (C.z - z0) / (C.z - B.z)`, add point `C + u * (B - C)` to list `L`

At the end, if `L` contains two points, that's your segment; otherwise, either the triangle does not intersect or it's a degenerate case. Make sure you check for possible divisions by zero.

Comment: This seems interesting, but I am not sure about the variables, I guess A B and C are the points of the triangle, but how can I multiply a value with them and where does the target z coordinate fit into all of this?

Comment: @Gerhman Yes, A B and C are the triangle points; multiplying a point with a value `k` consists in multiplying each of its x y and z components with `k`. Depending on the framework you use, there might already be a function or operator which does it for you. I assumed you wanted the intersection with the `z = 0` plane but I’ll update my answer so it works with an arbitrary `z0` value.

Answer (score 0):

You could just du a ray / plane intersection with two rays, after deciding how the triangle intersects with the plane (To intersect at all 1 point has to be on side A and two points on side B of the plane)

[This is my standard 'way-over-the-top' ressource for intersections](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html) you can look at different implementations and pick the one best suiting your need.

I little less complex is [this side](http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html), explaining what to do and providing a trianlge-ray algorithm in c (and a lot more under 'algorithms')